# How can I change an array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I do not know how to change or convert the array or if I am doing something wrong in my function?

I get this array, the number is words count:

```
[Food] => 1
[squid] => 1
[next] => 1
[leggings] => 1
```

In the end, I need this array without the words count:

```
[0] => Food
[1] => squid
[2] => next
[3] => leggings
```

That's my function:

```
$theString_1 = "$request->body, $request->titel, $request->articleText";
            // delete special character
            $theString_end = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 ä ü ö]+/", "", $theString_1 );

            // array of each word in the content separated by 'space'.
            $wordsArray = explode(' ', $theString_end);
            // count words with more than 3 charakters in texts
            $arrayCount = array_count_values(array_filter($wordsArray, function($v) {
                return strlen($v) > 3;
            }));
            //sort array most used word
            arsort($arrayCount);

            //get 4 most used word from the array
            $end = array_slice($arrayCount, 0,4);
```

Comment: array_keys($end);

Comment: thanks so much @splash58

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

The simplest one:

```php
$array = array_keys($end);
```

The second one:

```php
$array = [];
foreach($end as $key=>$value) {
    $array[] = $key;
}
```

Hope it helps.